# using google jQuery api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

How can I replace following lines with links to the Google jQuery API?

1st line is already done.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tab.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.pack.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

and maybe even this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" media="screen" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't...google doesn't host these plugins like they do jQuery Core and jQuery UI.

You can see what they host here: http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are not a part of the CDN as of yet. Plugins are mostly user built, so I doubt if there will be a CDN for that.